# How about getting rid of the [english] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

While we're are at full speed discussing various tags, I would like to bring to everyone's attention that we currently have 15 questions tagged [english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english). I don't think that that tag serves any meaningful purpose on a site that is *all about* English.

I took the liberty of removing the tag from quite a few questions in the past, whenever I came across one, but I don't want to clutter the main page by retagging 15 questions at once. So I would like to request a behind-the-scenes retag/deletion by the mods.

Things to note:

- there are currently two questions tagged *only* with [english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/english), [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7052/the-same-and-that-particular-one) and [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7763/how-to-write-this-letter-to-suite-for-situation).
- while we're at it, I have actually voted to close the latter one, please have a look; it could be considered too localized, too broad, NARQ or, for the most part, off-topic.
- not sure how to handle the tag in the long run, as we had brought the number of questions in it to 0 in the past, but that didn't prevent new questions from getting tagged with it. It would be nice to make it a synonym of, umm, well, that's the question. I can't think of a more meaningful tag this tag can be marked a synonym of; perhaps someone else can.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a pattern of sorts here here -- we ban the [apple] tag from apple.se, we ban the [wordpress] tag from wordpress.se .. etcetera.

I'll burninate this tag and add it to the tag blacklist.

Comment: Maybe the subdomain should be a banned tag by default?